# Disable automatic Id field generation in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Disable automatic Id field generation in Doctrine

this a part of my entity file:

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Variables
 * @ORM\Table(name="variables")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Repository\VariablesRepository")
 */

class Variables
{

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="variablesRef", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $variablesRef;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="variablesLibelle", type="string", length=250)
     */
    private $variablesLibelle;
```

when i try to create a schema :

erreur

> Property MyBundle\Entity\Employeursecteur::$id does not exist

i want to Disable automatic Id field generation in Doctrine
i don't need the id  Column 
please help

Comment: doctrine does need one or multiple fields to uniquely identify rows. and those fields have to be marked with `@Id` (or `@ORM\Id`). auto generated values are a different topic though. if you don't mark field(s) with @Id, it assumes, there is a property $id and tries to use that. since you don't have that ... mark the primary key with @Id.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a primary key field without a generated value you just have to set the strategy of generation to none:

```
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
```